# GD star rating function problem

Tags: php, plugin-gd-star-rating

If anyone can help me out with this you'll be a life saver.

I've been trying to use the wp_gdsr_render_review() function to add the results to my theme with no success. The results appear fine if I use the GD star rating widget so they are definitely being stored okay. Is there a known problem with wp_gdsr_render_review()? I created the function using the build tool.

Here is the exact code I used: 
wp_gdsr_render_review(get_the_id(), 54, 'oxygen', 16);

Please help!

Martyn

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the same functionality can be achieved with wp_gdsr_render_article() if you set it to read only